# Understanding the url part of a link_to, contain column name and value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, link-to

Please explain me the url part of this link_to.

url part

```
admin_user_path(user,{ user: { admin: !user.admin? } })
```

full link_to

```
<%= link_to "#{ user.admin? }", admin_user_path(user,
  { user: { admin: !user.admin? } }),
  method: :patch,
  class: "admin #{ user.admin ? 'btn-warning' : 'btn-info' } " 
%>
```

this is the html

```
<a class="admin btn-warning " data-method="patch" href="/admin/users/2?
user%5Badmin%5D=false" rel="nofollow">true</a>
```

`admin_user_path` generates `admin/user/`

`admin_user_path(user)` it generates `admin/user/:id`

`admin_user_path(user, options)` 
i Think, the option part contains value, that is accessible in the controller through the params? With this value, i can save it for the record with the id of :id.

Sry, im still new to rails, and i want to understand the options part. i know, it's the magic of rails, but maybe there is a bit more explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked at Rails Guide, [2.9 Creating Paths and URLs From Objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) : *"In addition to using the routing helpers, Rails can also create paths and URLs from an array of parameters."*

For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Ad details', magazine_ad_path(@magazine, @ad) %>
```

[link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) Api documentation

In your case

```
admin_user_path(user,{ user: { admin: !user.admin? } })
```

the option part creates a Boolean value, that’s available like you said in the Controller through parameters. Also, in your case I would recommend to check in your Controller that the user is actually admin, who accesses that path (authorization check).

Comment: thank you for the answer. The admin pages (controller) has a `before_action: authorize` check. Is it enough or should i check for admin before the record gets changed? Actually, i send this as a non Admin User `http://localhost:3000/admin/users/1?user%5Badmin%5D=true` and it didn't changed. lucky me :)

Comment: @AdvanceInBeginning, it sounds that your Controller is working OK if it's not updating when non-admin user is trying to update a value; so i think you have some kind of authorization check in place there already with the before_action: authorize filter. Also, I think your code is quite similar to the admin check found at Ruby on Rails tutorial book (I mean both controllers use filter to check admin users) https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users#sec-administrative_users